# Launching commands in separate windows using bash

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

How can I launch commands in new terminal windows?  I've tried the below

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Terminal "" -e "/usr/local/bin/zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties"
open -a Terminal "" -e "/usr/local/bin/kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties"
```

However I get

> the file /usr/local/bin/kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties does not exist.

The file does exist: e.g.
`ls /usr/local/bin/kafka-server-start` shows that the file is in there.

How can I tell it that the properities file is a parameter and not part of the path? Assuming this is the correct way to open a terminal with a new command.

I'm on MacOS Catalina, if it helps.

Comment: -e opens in TextEdit, also why use ""?

Comment: @nohillside I've tried now without "" -e thanks. I still get the same error

Comment: Don‘t think it needs quotes for the rest either, from looking at the error message you get

Comment: @nohillside It gives the same error with or without quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "/usr/local/bin/zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties"' -e 'do script "/usr/local/bin/kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties"' -e 'end tell'
```

It can also be done as:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript <<-EOF 
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "/usr/local/bin/zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties"
    do script "/usr/local/bin/kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties"
end tell
EOF
```

Or like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "/usr/local/bin/zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties"
    do script "/usr/local/bin/kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties"
end tell
```

Comment: probably close.  I get 118:118: syntax error: Expected end of line but found end of script. (-2741)

Comment: @Koenig Lear, I do not have the programs you're trying to start so I cannot test; however, these commands work for me when replaced with simple `do script say \"hello\"` or `do script say "hello"` depending on the method invoked.

Comment: It's working now (the OAS version) thanks, there was a missing backslash.

Comment: @Koenig Lear, Okay, thanks... I put the missing _slash_ `/` in.

Comment: @nohillside, Thanks... I totally missed that space. :)